# How to build next and previous links with php?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I use this code to get the informations about a certain id

```
$sql = dbquery("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `id` = ".$local_id." ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $video_id = $row["id"];
    $video_title = $row["title"];
}
```

Let's say the link of a page would be example.com/video.php?id=34

How can i get the next and previous $video_id and $video_title depending on the current id?

A problem is that i can't increase or decrease the value of the current id by 1 because the 35 or 33 may be deleted in the meanwhile...

How can i achieve this?

//edit

I have a very big problem: the previous link sends me to the right link but the next link always sends me to the last video added in the database.

If i go to the last or first videos added in the database i get an error because there are no more next and previous videos added.

Comment: If you can't do id-1 or id+1, then how can we know the previous/next videos? Is there a date order, or something like that? If yes, you (could) try selecting for a date< or > the date in this video, then set LIMIT 1. Just an idea.

Comment: Suppose you should get next id with "SELECT id FROM videos WHERE id > ".intval($id)." ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"
and previous id with  "SELECT id FROM videos WHERE id < ".inval($id)." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"

Comment: i get the same problem aven with this version with inval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps two more queries would work ...

```
 select id,title from videos where id < $local_id order by id desc limit 1
 select id,title from videos where id > $local_id order by id asc limit 1
```

Comment: Hi m3tsys, regarding the next always sending you to the last, ensure that you are using 'asc' for the order id, for the if already at first or if already at last, you could use mysql_num_rows() to let you know if anything is returned, and if 0 rows are returned, grab either the first or last id from the db

Comment: thank you, the not using of 'ASC' was causing the problem with the last entry in the db. i will try to use mysql_num_rows() and see if it will work.

Comment: I used mysql_num_rows() and now i don't have anymore errors. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `select` and `limit` to get that one row you want, i.e.,

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `id` < " . $local_id . " ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or use `>` and `ORDER BY`id`ASC` for the `next` video, instead of the `previous` I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go through**

```
// entry per page
$rowsPerPage = 3;

// Set page number
if(isset($_GET['page']))
    $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
else
    $pageNum = 1;
```

> Note: Following code is use to show/set next & previous page number.
>
> Note: If the current page is homepage then default $pageNum is 1 and
>   if $pageNum is set as 2, it will work as

```
if($pageNum){

    $PreviousPageNumber = $pageNum - 1;
    $NextPageNumber = $pageNum + 1;

    echo '<a href="?page='. $PreviousPageNumber .'>Previous Page</a>';
    echo '<a href="?page='. $NextPageNumber .'>Next Page</a>";
}
```

> Note: Following code is use to show record affected by page numbers

```
$GetPreviousRecord = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
```

> Note: The first, optional value of LIMIT is the start position. Note:
>   And the second required value is the number of rows to retrieve.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE LIMIT $GetPreviousRecord, $rowsPerPage";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

**And in last use the WHILE loop to get all records from database by using LIMIT.**