# Prev and next button for database results

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to build "Previous & Next" links to show records of my database, through pagination.
The connection is working fine. I just don't know how to build such links.
How can I do that?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test_page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width = "100%"><tr><td width="100%" align = "center">
<?php
$userName = "root";
$pass = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $userName, $pass) 
or die ("Nije uspostavljena veza sa Vasim mySQL serverom! <br />\n");
echo "Konekcija je uspostavljena! <br />\n";
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'vulkan')
or die ("Ne mogu da nadjem zadatu bazu! <br />\n");
echo ("Baza je pronadjena! <br />\n");
echo "<br /> <br /> <br />";
$id=$_GET['id'];
$currentid=$id;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from ploce_pod where id=$currentid");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$currentid=$row['id'];
}
$resultPrev = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from ploce_pod where id<$currentid 
LIMIT 1");
while($prevRow = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPrev))
{
$previd = $prevRow['id'];
}
$resultNext = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from ploce_pod where id>$currentid 
LIMIT 1");
while($nextRow = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNext))
{
$nextid = $nextRow['id'];
}
//here is print table, this is OK
mysqli_close($conn);
echo ("Baza je otkacena! <br />\n");
?>
<p>
<a href="Index.php?id=<?php echo $previd; ?>">prethodni</a>
<a href="Index.php?id=<?php echo $nextid; ?>">sledeci</a>
</p>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a question as old as time. It's highly recommended to search, before asking. For example, [How to build next and previous links with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843699/how-to-build-next-and-previous-links-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [PHP Pagination](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html)

```
<?php
    /*
        Place code to connect to your DB here.
    */
    include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.

    $tbl_name="";       //your table name
    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "filename.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 2;                                 //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>

    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        // Your while loop here

        }
    ?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jess, but I don't need pagination, just php code to call one by one record (in same php page) by clik on link (or button, that is no matter).